# WCF with reference to external web service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have made a WCF which draws data from a ms sql db and from an external WCF.
When i debug the service it works fine, but once I try it in the real world, I get this error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: There was no endpoint listening at http://10.11.11.22/AIM/AIMIS that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Some of the app.config:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="AdapterFacadeBinding" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://10.11.11.22/AIM/AIMIS" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="AdapterFacadeBinding" contract="AIMISWS.AdapterFacadePortType"
    name="AdapterFacadePort" />
</client>
<services>
  <service name="EcoGridIBMExport.CustomerService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="EcoGridIBMExport.ICustomerService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/EcoGridIBMExport/Service1/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

and on the client app I connect like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CustomerServiceClient client = new CustomerServiceClient();  
    Console.WriteLine(client.GetMeter());
    Console.ReadLine();

    client.Close();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `See InnerException, if present, for more details.` Just call `ToString` on the exception to get what people need to help you.  It includes the type, message, and stack trace for the exception and all inner exceptions.

Comment: The problem is not with your client connection to CustomerService, but a problem with the CustomerService connecting to the AIMISWS service

Comment: Is this what you wont to see:

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wont to see:

System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: There was no endpoint listening at http://10.11.11.22/AIM/AIMIS that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. (Fejloplysningerne er lig med En ExceptionDetail, som sandsynligvis er oprettet af IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, med værdien:
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://10.11.11.22/AIM/AIMIS that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ----> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.11.11.22:80
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- Slut på staksporingen for oplysninger...).